# How to paint a cell in column with devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, cell, devexpress-mvc

I need to paint a cell only in column with name "Summa". I tried this and it isn't work:

```
private void gridView_Tasks_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
        {
             if (e.Column.FieldName == "Summa") e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Also I tried this:

e.Column.AppearanceCell.Options.UseForeColor = true;
e.Column.AppearanceCell.ForeColor = Color.Red;

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoint to that line? Does is execute? Maybe add `e.DisplayText = "xy";` to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added your string and could find correct "if" instruction. To exclude similar problems you need to write correct Name of gridColumn and replace `e.Column.FieldName` with `e.Column.Name` in if statement. Correct code:                                                                                                          
`private void gridView_Tasks_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) { if (e.Column.Name == "gridColumn_Tasks_Summa") e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Red; }`

Comment: Great! However (if somebody else reads this in the future) the purpuse of properties [FieldName](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.FieldName) is completely different than the purpose of property [Name](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.Name).